# Incorrect index when scrolling in view

Tags: python, qt, pyside

The idea is to emit the index so I can catch it somewhere else and update information from that index. It works great - except when I scroll (while keeping the mouse still) the correct indices are not emitted. I'm guessing this is because the wheelEvent is firing before the actual scrolling happens. I'm a little stuck here though.

```
class View(QtGui.QTreeView):
   hovered = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QModelIndex)

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(View, self).__init__(parent)

      self.setMouseTracking(True)

   def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
      index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(self.indexAt(event.pos()))
      if index.isValid():
         self.hovered.emit(index)

      super(TreeView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

   def wheelEvent(self, event):
      index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(self.indexAt(event.pos()))
      if index.isValid():
         self.hovered.emit(index)

      super(TreeView, self).wheelEvent(event)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little dumb now. The problem was exactly what I was saying earlier. The actual scrolling was happening after I was grabbing the index because I was calling the super class method last (duh!). All I had to do was move the super class method to the top.

Answer (score 3):

It is not safe to save `QModelIndex` between different event. You need to use `QPersistentModelIndex` instead.